# How to exclude inherited methods from method listing, Reflection (PHP)

Tags: php, class, reflection

I'm trying to list all methods / properties of a class in PHP using reflection. The simple listing works.

But it list properties and methods of the base class too. How can I filter this?

tks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that [`ReflectionMethod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) has the method [`getDeclaringClass()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getdeclaringclass.php). This method returns the class where the method was delcared in. Too only display methods that where declared in your class you should try this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('YourClass');

foreach($class->getMethods() as $m) {
    if($m->getDeclaringClass()->getName() === 'YourClass') {
        echo $m->getName(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

where `YourClass` is something like this:

```
class YourClass extends DOMDocument {


    public function doSomething() {
        // ...
    }


    public function doSomethingElse() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that it works the same with properties and constants

Comment: +1 for both editing question and nice answer

Comment: Thanks! was hard to understand :)